Borderless C++ window doesn't trigger Windows 11's docking panel
I recently created a window with C++ and the Win32 API. I want to make a custom titlebar for it (I overrode WM_NCHITTEST to be able to drag it anywhere):
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK window_proc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (uMsg == WM_NCHITTEST) {
        LRESULT hit = DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        if (hit == HTCLIENT) hit = HTCAPTION;
        return hit;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int) {
    WNDCLASSW window_class = {
        NULL, window_proc, NULL,NULL, hInstance,
        NULL, LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW),
        NULL, NULL, L"minimal_example_window"
    }; RegisterClassW(&window_class);
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(
        L"minimal_example_window", L"",
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP | WS_SIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        1200,
        800,
        NULL,NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
    );

    MSG msg; while (GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    { TranslateMessage(&msg); DispatchMessageW(&msg); }
    
    return 0;
}

But, when I do not have the WS_SIZEBOX (or WS_THICKFRAME) and the WS_MAXIMIZEBOX style on the window, dragging it to the top of the screen doesn't trigger Windows 11's dock popup.
I tried a lot of different window styles listed in Window Styles Win32 Docs, with no success.
For the record, I use clang++ 17.0.6 x86_64-w64-windows-gnu posix
Any help?

Sounds like the window needs to be resizable in order to be snappable.

On a side note, another way to let your border-less window be draggable without having to hook WM_NCHITTEST is to instead have an WM_LBUTTONDOWN handler send your window a WM_SYSCOMMAND message with its wParam set to the undocumented SC_DRAGMOVE (0xF012, aka SC_MOVE+2) command. That will trigger the same functionality that happens when the user holds down and drags a normal titlebar.

That is correct and I found an answer somewhere that used SC_SIZE+9. I tried it with no luck. But yes it is more concise.

I guess I'll just have to extend the WM_NCPAINT event and paint over the little white bar.

Whether your issue has been solved? Have you got any updates?

Yes the issue has been solved I'm going to create a solution and close the issue. Thank you for reminding me.

Looks like Windows's docking system requires the window to be resizable.
The solution is painting over the original titlebar and creating a custom HitTest function to be able to resize the window normally.
This article goes into great detail:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/customframe
